# How to set max width for the ScrollView content without nesting view?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack

What I want to achieve is to set some max width for components in one place to make all the views looking familiar when the parent width is stretched to large value (e.g. when orientation changes to landscape)

Let's say we have a `ScrollView` with container view and some `TextView`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum..."/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum..."/>
        
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now, I want to set the max width for the `TextView`s to 300 dp. I can just use the
`ConstraintLayout` and set `layout_constraintWidth_max` to each of the `TextView`s, but I would like to set it only in one place. In order to do that, I can nest the `LinearLayout` into `ConstraintLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_max="300dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum..." />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum..." />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It gives me the desired results, but the pitfall of this solution is that I have to nest the views which [is not the recommended approach](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies).

The question is, how to achieve easily set max width for all children without nesting the parent views?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want multiple items to look same, you should use style, and set it to all items. In your style just add everything that is same for all views like this:

```
<style name="NewStyle">
    <item name="android:maxWidth">300dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:text">Lorem ipsum...</item>
</style>
```

If you have only one similarity than you can extract 300dp to dimens.xml and use it in all places.
One more solution would be:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"...
```